# How to upload an image to Cloudinary with fetch

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload a file to Cloudinary using fetch from my front-end. I've tried piecing together the way to do it from the documentation and StackOverflow answers, but I get a 400 error:

```js
export async function uploadImageToCloudinary(file: File) {
  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
  const fetched = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      file,
      cloud_name: cloudName,
      upload_preset: "unsigned",
    }),
  });
  const parsed = await fetched.json()
  console.log({
    parsed // 400 error, message: "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"
  });
}
```

It says upload preset must be specified, so I must have the above code wrong. My Cloudinary Settings have the 'unsigned' upload preset here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works if I replace the `body: JSON.stringify(...)` with `const data = new FormData()...`. I don't know why, but this works:

```js
export async function uploadImageToCloudinary(file: File) {
  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', file);
  data.append('upload_preset', 'unsigned');

  const fetched = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    body: data,
  });
  const parsed = await fetched.json()
  console.log({
    parsed // 200, success!
  });
}
```

Comment: If you want to use JSON then the "file" parameter needs to contain data that is serializable into JSON - i.e. remote URL or S3/GCS path that returns the image or the asset as a Base64 string. If your data is a byte array then that won't be possible to send it in JSON format hence the need for FormData.